# Are there any efficient spider traps on minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a full suit of iron armour but I can't kill any spiders without dying myself. I was wondering if there was a simple yet efficient spider trap/killer in Minecraft. I do not have any cacti on my island and i havent found lava yet either. What i am looking for is the plans for a spider grinder.

Comment: do you have a spawner? or just finding the spiders at night?

Comment: Where are you trying to kill spiders? In mineshafts/caves, or above ground?

Comment: I am on a smallish island and above ground but some other mobs see me and i sometimes find my self fighting with a swarm of spiders. The skeletons and zombies seem to hang around the waters edge though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This Link](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Traps) from Minecraft wiki shall guide you through a huge number of simple traps. These are designed to trap or trick other players or mobs automatically. Some traps even kill...

However, I shall briefly sum up the most popular designs for trapping spiders.

**Land Mine**
For a simple land mine a 1 by 1 hole two blocks deep. Next put one piece of TNT at the bottom and cover it with a block that looks natural to the area(a stone block in a cave ect.). After that just put a pressure plate on top and it's done. If a mob or player steps on it, It will go off.
Note: When using a wooden pressure plates dropped items will trigger the TNT and the delay and noise of the TNT may alert the victim.

**More Advanced** I pay attention to Kiershar's youtube channel, and based my mob trap off of his [videos](http://www.youtube.c...notation_999551). The biggest problem with his grinder as well as many other traps is that it does not kill spiders very efficiently, and sometimes, not at all. I've seen videos of elaborate fixes to this problem, but I can't believe someone hasn't seemed to have done what I've done.

[image: grinder]
Here is my grinder. Just like Kiershar's, I have a 3X2 lava pool running over a couple of ladders with a 1X2 space below where items but not mobs can fall through. The sand block at the bottom left is where a cactus would sit if this were Kiershar's trap. As you can see, I have omitted this as well as a block below the ladders for keeping spiders from falling through because this is not where they will be dying (note the string floating by).

This is how they die:
[image: How they die]

Here is the start of that same channel that has the lava at the end. The beginning of the channel should have another channel one block higher flowing into it and a cactus sitting on top of that sand block. The length of the channel after that doesn't matter, but this part is crucial. This creates a 2 block high, one block wide space that all other mobs can go through, but not spiders. Taking advantage of the fact that spiders are the only 2 block wide mob is what makes this work.

[image: channel start]
Here is another view of the beginning of this channel with the cactus placed and the other channel filled in. A water block should be placed to the right of the cactus.

[image: channel 2]
Placing that water block leads to a water current that looks like this. 1 block wide mobs will fall in and most likely float behind the cactus, but soon after will float to the lava and die. Spiders however, will sit here unless there is another mob behind them. They will block the entire 2 block wide entrance to this channel, so they must die first, which they will because the mob behind them will push them directly into the cactus at the 2 block high level. This always works, and no other mobs will flow through until the spider dies.

[image: spider killer in action]
Here's the spider killer in action. As you can see, the spider floats to the block at the level of the cactus and dies there. This doesn't depend on whether the spider is jumping; it's just somehow levitating above thin air. The ceiling should be filled in at the block above the cactus, though, to make sure the spider stops here.

[image: spider kill spider]
Spiders will also kill each other this way. No more spiders clogging your trap!
Taken from [here](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/266253-easiest-way-to-kill-spiders-in-your-mob-trap/).

Comment: This does nothing to answer the question. An explanation of spider traps is what the OP is after.

Comment: @ChrisF The link provides the explanation on how to trap creatures small and large...

Comment: It may well do. But what happens if the link dies? (Unlikely but it has happened). Then this answer will be useless as it doesn't stand on it's own.

Comment: ah right. Well informed. I'll correct.

Comment: I think i might be able to make a trap alot easier if i had lava and cacti.

Comment: Hence why its the more advanced option. Try looking at the wiki, and remembering that everything you can see you can make by having the base items required.

Comment: you don't need the cactus. Lava is sufficient if the water has a drop of 1 field just before the ladders.

Comment: no lava either.

Answer (score 3):

If you're fighting spiders that are out in the open in the day, try setting fires near them so that they take damage without getting angry.

At night, try to arrange things so there's a one-meter gap they can't get through.

If you find a spider spawner, light the room completely, arrange the room so it's only got one exit, and plant one or two cacti on either side of the exit so that any spider that tries to get to you will press itself to death on the cactus.  Set up water flow so that any string dropped by the spider will flow toward you.

Note:  spiders that kill themselves this way will not drop any XP or spider eyes.  You can make a bunch of stone swords, though, and whack the spiders while they try to get at you; they can't squeeze through a one-meter gap.

(Of course, if you find the tiny blue POISON spiders, they'll jump right through.  I suggest avoiding those; they don't drop anything different.)

Comment: The only problem is there isnt any cacti on my island or i would have done this. and i just want the trap for string.

Comment: Will the spiders drop string if they kill themselves.

Answer (score 1):

IMO Spiders are the easiest mob to predict. A "fighting retreat" as other folks have posited works...

But the best way I have found is simply click with a sword like a madman - the old spam-the-sword routine, wall of blades, etc. The idea is that the short knockback you get from a sword hit keeps the mob from hitting you. If it's not working as well, try using a sword with knockback enchantment. You'll get more time to juggle.

- **Spiders** will jump right into your sword. I barely take damage.
- **Cave spiders** are a little tougher to hit. Assume you're going to get poisoned.
- Quite effective on **zombies**
- So-so on *skeletons* (melee vs. skeletons is always risky)
- Not great on *creepers*. The problem is you only get about two hits before they explode. Hit and run tactics work better. You can soften them up with arrows, though.
- Doesn't work well on *zombie pigmen*, unless you're **one block above or below** them, in which case it works *gangbusters* and you can take on a steady stream of piggies without taking a hit (aim at feet when you are below them; aim at their head when you're above them). However, you won't be able to fend off more than two in open combat without a knockback sword or willingness to take a lot of hits. If you have a really narrow tunnel, you can do groups of 4-5 with only a cramp in your mouse hand.
- Not useful on *spider jockeys* (you get the spider, but the skeleton shoots you a few times)
- Not useful on *ghasts* - if you can actually get close enough to hit them
- Terrible on *ghast fireballs*. One well-timed strike is better.
- Works well on **slimes**
- Not so hot on *magma cubes*. The timing just seems different...
- Great on **blazes** - if you're drinking fire resist. An experienced player can kill blazes without getting set on fire... but don't take that chance.
- A waste of clicks on *endermen* - you only get one hit in and they teleport away. No need to spam the sword strikes.

Comment: to kill a creeper you hit it and run and if it lights the fuse it will stop if your far enough away. hit it again and run.

Comment: @mrminecraft3000: yes hence my use of the phrase "hit and run tactics work better". Remember - my answer is talking about just running in and clicking like you're playing a Diablo game, because that works *really* well for Spiders.

Answer (score 0):

To fight a spider that isn't aggroed, just walk up to it and hit it multiple times with a stone or better sword. It will almost always die before it will get aggroed and attack you. Note this is only possible during the day.

For fighting spiders that are aggroed with you, it is best done with open, flat space behind you or in a good sized body of water. In water, attack the spider and retreat. Repeat until the spider is dead. The water slows down the spider and keeps it from being able to leap effectively. (Note: this is a good way to kill creepers as well. Hit it once, and retreat at full speed until it is no longer charged. Then close to melee range, hit it, and retreat. Repeat until it is dead.)

For land melee battles with spiders, attack and retreat if you can. Otherwise, attack, strafe in the space available, and attack more. The trick is to attack a lot and move every couple of seconds so the spider will spend its time turning or will leap at where you were.

The main trouble with fighting in water is learning to swim and attack at the same time.

Spider grinders are possible. Several are documented on the minecraft wiki, and from what I recall, some even have videos of how to construct them.

Comment: Some other tips: use a BOW (especially with creepers!). Spiders are also two large: if you build 'columns' around the spawner area with only 1 block between the columns, you can pass (and hit) between them, but spiders can't. The easiest for of XP farm: spiders drop until they are only one-hit from death, and you finish them from between the columns.

Answer (score 0):

If spiders are sneaking into your home, try adding overhangs. Add a 2 block or one block overhang every at every other block near the top of your house, and you'll prevent spiders from entering your home as well as crushing the skeletons on spider jockeys.

For actually fighting spiders, the strategy is always a bit different. If it's in the night, the best advice is to prevent them from jumping by getting close to them and repeatedly hit them until they die (note that this is not a good strategy for dealing with creepers). In daylight, just try to avoid them, but if you need the string, just apply the previous method.

If you lack netherrack or cacti, then you *could* make a piston based grinder. Note that this is slightly more difficult than the other types, but only relies on a small source of redstone and glass. Underneath the spawner, dig a rectangular 3x3 box. Fill the horizontal edges of the box with pistons facing the middle as well as pieces of stone, so it looks like the following:

```
     R    R
     RSSSSR
     PS--SP
RRRRRPS--SPRRRRR
     PS--SP
     RSSSSR
     R    R
```

Assuming that P is piston and S is stone, and R is redstone. Then make sure that all the redstone is attached to a pulser (rapid clock) that is beating quickly. When you want to get the string/eyes, deactivate the pulser, turn on the lights, and get the items.

Answer (score 0):

'hit and run, hit and run' is the easiest way to kill a spider. when i was starting a survival world, and was late on finding wood, i found that when you make a smallish house, with just one block to move around,no roof, spiders could not get in. great way to hide if a spider is racing at you, make one out of dirt.

```
 WWW               
 W W              
 W W               
 W W              
 WWW
```

(W=wood)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried a simple trick with cacti and water. If you don't have cacti then its easy to find on a desert, just go during the day in a boat. The trick is to make a bowl in the ground by mining the dirt pretty big and filling it with water running towards the center. Then have a wall of cacti at least two blocks from the end all the way around and wait in the center for anything dropped to flow towards you. If skeletons come and can hit you try a wall of glass to allow yourself to be seen but I have rarely seen those on my island and haven't needed it.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a space three by three blocks wide and one block deep, with the bottom made of obsidian and the sides made of gold. This is some weird glitch that will kill every spider or silverfish (not cave spiders) that is 32 blocks in reach if you stand in the middle of the hole. This is best at night, so in the morning, you can collect all the string. The spiders never drop any eyes this way though, and this glitch doesn't kill spiders above the hole, so I suggest you make this on a high point. Then no spiders can catch you by surprise from above.

Comment: You'll need to back this up with some evidence, gold and obsidian don't have any dangerous properties.

Answer (score -1):

I just attack as it comes and run away if my health is low. I make large, roofed houses so no mobs can come in. In day, where it is light, the spiders are neutral. At night, they are constantly aggressive to you. In the pocket edition, in creative, all mobs are neutral or passive when they spawn, but night can't. Making a mini spider shelter that is roofed will allow you to visit the spider but he can't attack you by leaping. This only works if the roof is one block above the open block layer. In day, spiders might remain neutral if attacked in water. No mob can try and kill you when you're in water at least 3 blocks deep or in an underwater house. Spider jockeys are unseen to me. I only play the pocket edition. Here are passive mobs:
Mooshroom, cow, pig, sheep, chicken, villager, tamed wolf                  Neutral mobs: 
Iron Golem, Enderman, wild wolf, spider in light, zombie pigman                           Hostile mobs:
attacked iron golem, attacked wild wolf, spider in night and attacked in day, provoked enderman,
slime, zombie, creeper, skeleton, cave spider at night and attacked in day, silverfish, ender dragon, ghast, magma cube, wild ore chickens, attacked zombie pigman
   Regular spiders are 2 blocks wide, 2 blocks long, and 1 block tall. Ender spiders are 2 blocks long, 2 blocks wide, and 1 1/2 blocks tall. Cave spiders are 1 block long, 1 block wide, and 1/2 block tall. Cave spiders have 12 health points. Regular ones have 16 health points. In the pocket edition, many of these mobs were recently added.