# How to purge a corridor of spiders?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've blocked off a corridor with a spider spawner in an abandoned mine with some stone. Then I loitered far too long outside. The sounds from inside suggest breaking the stone is a guaranteed suicide. I'm looking for good, sure-fire way to purge the corridor for good.

I have some TNT saved up, not a lot. I have access to lava. I have enough iron and gold, just a few diamonds though. Plenty of Redstone too and various goodies, I haven't been to Nether though.

I though of using a piston to push a long line of TNT in, that's just 12 blocks though and I'm really not sure how long the corridor is. I tried lava in creative mode but getting it all flooded without spiders escaping may be hard.

The entrance is blocked with block of wood pillars, not the fencepost ones, so I can't even look inside safely.

Any good ideas?

Comment: remember that light near the spawner is decreasing its spawn rate

Comment: Place and sleep bed somewhere close.  Store all of your stuff in a chest.  Grab some torches and a sword or two.  Then simply run in and attack like mad while placing torches.  If you fail, simply try again.  :p

Comment: Is that a cave spider spawner? If they're normal spiders you can safely dig a 1x1 hole without letting them escape, however you can't do that if they're cave spiders ('cause they're smaller).

Comment: @AlvinWong: Cave spider, the small ones. Yesterday I lost my enchanted diamond pick and bunch of other stuff to them. Dug a hole in the wall. Spider jumps in from the other side. Spider bites. Knockback throws me down from a cliff into the middle of a lake of lava. Poison+fall+lava, it was like 4 seconds from healthy, armored and safe to dead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way I always tackle this is with an advancing wall of fence posts. Assuming you have mine shafts nearby (since that is where these spawners usually show up) go grab a whole bunch of them.

Now, you are probably in a 3-by-3 shaft, so go to the wall of wood pillars and place a 3-by-3 wall of fence posts over it. Next, go to one of the side walls and break out the middle block (the one at head height) which is immediately adjacent to a fence post you just placed. This will make a gap on the side of the fence wall that is wide enough for you to mine away or place blocks behind the fence wall, but narrow enough that cave spiders can't fit through.

Beware, the spiders can still reach you to hit you if you are too near the gap, so maintain a safe distance and time your attacks when the spiders approach the gap. Once you clear enough of them out, you can walk up to the gap and start to place another 3-by-3 fence wall ahead of where the current one is. Then you can break the first fence wall and advance.

Lather, rinse, repeat and eventually you will get close enough to the spawner to either destroy it or place torches to deactivate it. It can take some time but it will keep you from getting killed under a tidal wave of angry poisonous spiders.

Comment: That's a brilliant use of the unusual bounding box of fences.

Answer (score 4):

Can you leave and come back? The most surefire way to purge it is to move far enough away that the spiders de-spawn, and then you simply return and quickly open it and disable the spawner.

Comment: Whenever I've been near a spider spawner there was a plenty of them even if I came there after a longish delay. Besides... where's the challenge in that?! :D

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you need to do:

1. Make a lot of pressure plates
2. place the pressure plates in front of where you will bust open the spider entrance
3. place a lot of TNT at the pressure plates so they can blow up
4. Break open the spider entrance and RUN!
5. Come back and place torches around the spider trap to disable it
6. This is optional, but you can make a [spider trap](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/65175/are-there-any-efficient-spider-traps-on-minecraft?rq=1)
7. You are done and with unlimited access to string and spider eyes

Answer (score 1):

I would break the wood pillars and replace them (one by one) with fenceposts, carefully of course. That way at least you could see what you were getting into. After that, you really have a few issues:

- You need to eliminate the spiderwebs that will keep you from getting to the spawner
- You need to not die from the spider onslaught
- You need to get to the spawner and destroy it

For me, the hardest part of this process is almost always the "getting rid of all the spiderwebs" part. You can't burn them (or at least, last time I tried you couldn't) using a flint, and you would waste TNT blowing them up. If you can get above the room, I would do that. Make a single block hole and put a bucket of lava into it, which will fall and spread out. That will kill at least some of the spiders. While that is running, go back to one of the sides (the one in the corridor that you blocked off with wood, presumably) and make a single hole at eye level. Between the lava and you whacking at the spiders, you will be able to make a pretty big dent. Once you get enough spiders and spiderwebs wiped out, just run in and put a torch on the spider spawner. Once that's done, you can take your time - either farming the spiders, or just killing them entirely.

Comment: Getting rid of the webs using shears is the fastest. Also if you place a pair of blocks not right between the fenceposts but a block before or after them, you can hack both at the webs and at the spiders and they won't pass - they can still hurt you though.

Comment: The hole in the ceiling is a great idea.

Answer (score 1):

Use a potion of invisibility, clean out spider webs with shears, and light up corridor.  Come back armored up and kill any remaining spiders.

Answer (score 0):

you also could just go to the spawner's cobblestone roof and dig out a block, and pour some lava down, if a/some spider/spiders come out, kill it with a sword.If it/they poisons/poison you have a few buckets of milk just in case(milk was given the ability to cure poison)and don't forget to get diamond armor enchanted with protection. you also could dig some more holes in the roof while the lavas' running and place down some TNT in the holes and activate them with redstone torches. That should take care of the spiders.if there are any left just kill them.

P.S. Don't forget to run away after activating the TNT.